# Format the logs using logback

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, logback

I'm developping an application spring-boot. I use logback for logs side. I need to format the logs like this format.

```
aaa-mm-dd HH:mm:ss ## level ## TheNameOfMyApplication ## typeOfLogs ## class  ## message
```

this is a snippet of my file logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} ## %-5level## TheNameofMyApplication ## %logger{36}##%msg%n
        </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.myapp" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

What can I do to pass in the **logger.info()** parameter, for example, the type of my logs. I have three types:

- technical, application and other

Best regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context), using the `%X` specifier within the PatternLayout. Your pattern should look like:

```
<Pattern>
    %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} ## %-5level%X{nameofapplication} %logger{36}##%msg%n
</Pattern>
```

And then, your code:

```
 MDC.put("nameofapplication", "technical");
```

Have a look to the documentation: [LOGBack - Mapped Diagnostic Context](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html)

---

For `slf4j/logback`, in order to set a MDC default value, when the entry has not been specified, you need to use the separator `:-` like:

```
%{variable:-default value}
```

So, your pattern should be:

```
<Pattern>
    %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} ## %-5level%X{nameofapplication:-technical} %logger{36}##%msg%n
</Pattern>
```

Comment: Thanks @alfcope it works for me. is there any possiblilty to set a default value for that variable ?

Comment: Is it possible to call MDC.put("nameofapplication", "technical") one time in each classe for exampe just after `private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClassTest.class);`   and then MDC.put("nameofapplication", "technical")

Comment: I do not think that is possible as MDC manages data on a per thread basis. As the documentation says MDC operations such as put() and get() affect only the MDC of the current thread. In a multi thread app, like web application, different requests are going to be handled by different threads.